# How to prevent the other styles to not apply inside the react div or component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
const [html, setHtml] = useState<string>("");
<div>
{html ? parse(html):""}
</div>
```

html is a template with its style but when it renders the other styles of the application override it. i want to prevent that common style of the application should not apply in html content and also html contents style should not apply to other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the CSS `all` property and target all the children that come within the div container and override their styles moving forward, enabling you to apply styles that come within HTML template.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

you can define your CSS style as

```css
/* Targets all the elements inside the div */
div * { 
   all: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also bumped into a similar issue. Restyling each dom node in an HTML template might make things more complicated to maintain in the long run. Changing the global application might also require handling those changes in the HTML markup as well. To make things simple, I created a simple component that uses iframe and renders the markup in isolation making template secure and separated.

```js
const Webview = function(props) {
  const iFrameRef = useRef();

  function resizeIframe() {
    const height = parseInt(iFrameRef.current.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight, 10);
    let offset = 32;
    iFrameRef.current.style.height = (height + offset) + "px";
    iFrameRef.current.contentWindow.document.body.style.margin = "0px";
  }

  const body = useMemo(() => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(props.body, 'text/html');
    // doc has all the HTML template parsed and stored in memory. you can make changes here before making it available to the iframe 
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <title>Email</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
          <style>
           /* You can also add your global styles here */
            * { 
              font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            }
          </style>
         </head>
         <body>
          ${doc.body.innerHTML}
         </body>
    </html>`
  }, [props.body])

  return (
    <iframe
      ref={iFrameRef}
      className={props.className}
      srcDoc={body}
      onLoad={resizeIframe}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: yes sir, your solution is currect but iframe causes the security issues in websites, is there another solution to this problem, then please write a solution.

Comment: as a precaution, I would suggest using some type of html sanitizer that can remove any potentially unwanted code blocks such as script tags, unwanted event bindings, unwanted attributes such as xlink:href. 

You can also try to explore sandbox attribute in iframe that can also disable some features making it more secure. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#sandbox